# sharepoint 2013 calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online

What is the difference between Calendar

[image]

and the normal calendar

[image] ?

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference. What you see is the icon for the calendar from SharePoint 2010, and the second is for 2013. While migrating a 2010 farm to 2013, the icons are not updated.

While it can be annoying to have the old icons, there is no impact to the functionality.